# Почему Socket не выполняется?

Tags: android, сервер, сокет, textview, клиент

Почему в TextView последнее что записывается это 1.5??

```
public void clickButton (View view){
    textView.setText("connect");
int serverPort = 8888; // здесь обязательно нужно указать порт к которому привязывается сервер.
String address = "192.168.1.6"; // это IP-адрес компьютера, где исполняется наша серверная программа.
// Здесь указан адрес того самого компьютера где будет исполняться и клиент.
textView.setText("1");
try {
    InetAddress ia = Inet4Address.getByName(address);
    textView.setText("1.5");
    Socket socket = new Socket(ia,serverPort); // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
    textView.setText("2");
    // Берем входной и выходной потоки сокета, теперь можем получать и отсылать данные клиентом.
    InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
    textView.setText("3");
    // Конвертируем потоки в другой тип, чтоб легче обрабатывать текстовые сообщения.
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
    textView.setText("4");
    // Создаем поток для чтения с клавиатуры.
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    textView.setText("5");
    String line = null;
    line = "connect";
    out.writeUTF(line);
    out.flush();
    textView.setText("lalka");
} catch (Exception x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Comment: Может стоит приложить стектрейс ошибки?  За вас этот  код компилировать и искать ошибку врядли кто то будет.  Могу предположить что ошибка возникает их за того, что вы устанавливаете сетевое соединение в основном потоке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь. Сам уже разобрался. В манифесте добавил права.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите ваше решение чуть-чуть более подробно.